# Give an url to my server adress with port

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

I have a server url turn into aws EC2 instance.

Actually i access to it using 1.2.3.4:8000 (the port specification is necessay to get it).

I want to give it an URL instead. Example: 1.2.3.4:8000 ==> www.mywebsite.com

Help me please to find a way to do that.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add a load balancer (ELB) that points port 80/443 at port 8000 on your server. Point your domain at that load balancer via Route 53's DNS tools.